# XCode 4.4.1: Can't Deploy to Device or Simulator: Unsupported architecture

Tags: iphone, xcode, arm, xcode4.4

I'm having some trouble deploying to any device in XCode 4.4. I have only tested on armv7 devices, but I only wish to deploy to armv7. The application compiles without issue.

---

[image: Choose a destination with a supported architecture in order to run on this device]

*Device Error*

---

[image: The selected destination does not support the architecture for which the selected software is built. Switch to a destination that supports that architecture in order to run the selected software.]

*Simulator Error*

---

I have checked that the Architectures and the Valid Architectures in the build settings **contain only armv7**.

I'm working in an XCode Workspace with one project and one subproject. The subproject creates a static library which acts as a target dependancy to the main project.

Other questions suggest that the **deployment target might be wrong, but I checked this** too and it is set to iOS4.0 for all projects and targets. (All devices are iOS5.0 +)

Does anyone have any suggestions please?

Comment: shouldn't it be i386 for simulator..?

Comment: Perhaps, but it doesn't run on the device either.

Comment: I've had a similar problem which both arrived and departed without any apparent cause (within a few minutes). I'd love to know the reason.

Comment: This is a new project and I did have it running on both simulator and device, but may well have fiddled some setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though I couldn't find exactly why this was happening. I fixed it by removing the project data.

- Close XCode
- Open Terminal
- `cd` to your .xcodeproj directory
- Recursively delete any project data files associated with the current user name

  - `find . -name "YOUR_OSX_USERNAME_HERE*" | xargs rm -rf`
- Reopen XCode
- Just for luck, do a clean build

### Edit

Had this error again and wasn't solved by the above steps alone. There were two other factors:

- Make sure **Info.plist isn't part of the Target Membership**
- Clear `DerivedData`

  - Quit Xcode and iPhone simulator
  - Unplug your devices
  - Goto `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/`
  - Delete all data under this folder
  - Start Xcode again and run your project

Answer (score 0):

I've found that Xcode really seems to like '$(ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT)' for 'Architectures'. If its not set to that try it, 'Valid Architectures' with armv7.

Just curious - if building for newer phones only, why not use a deployment target of 4.3? You'll be able to use some of the new block technologies not in the earlier releases.

Comment: `You'll be able to use some of the new block technologies not in the earlier releases.` - Blocks are available from 4.0 and are indeed one of the reasons why the deployment target isn't lower. [Apple Doc on Blocks](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/00_Introduction.html)

Comment: Unfortunately, these are the values I already had. I tried it the other way, no change